# Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING (when using charindex - only for certain char)

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a database where the majority of testid have information in parentheses which I want to extract. So I've written (simplified version)

```
select 
case when wt.testid like '%(%)%' 
then substring(wt.testid, 
        charindex('(',wt.testid)+1, 
        (charindex(')',wt.testid) - charindex('(',wt.testid) - 1)
        )
```

which is working just fine, but not all of these tests have this format, some have this information after an underscore and before a space,

so I added this extra part

```
else substring(wt.testid, 
        charindex('_',wt.testid)+1, 
        (charindex(' ',wt.testid) - charindex('_',wt.testid) -1)
        )
```

but for some reason this causes 'Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function.'

If I remove the -1 then the query works, which suggests that the -1 is causing the length parameter to be negative, but all of the results of the query have a space and an underscore, and when I pass

```
(charindex(' ',wt.testid) - charindex('_',wt.testid) -1)
```

into my select I always get positive values, so I don't know what's going on.

Comment: Do you also have values in `testid` that *don't* contain spaces and underscores but that are filtered out via `ON` or `WHERE` clause predicates?

Comment: You could easily find the offending values by explicitly filtering on `WHERE (charindex(' ',wt.testid) - charindex('_',wt.testid) -1) < 0` in the original query, and then look at things more closely. The simple response to "I always get positive values" would be "well then `SUBSTRING` will never fail", but it does, so your assumptions must have a flaw somewhere.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see these comments, but Damien_The_Unbeliever's other answer nailed it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you have filters that mean that only results containing parentheses or the underscore and space format are returned in your result set, SQL Server will *not* guarantee not to evaluate some expressions eagerly and generate errors for rows which do not actually contribute to the final result.

You can *usually* cope with this by making judicious use of `CASE` expressions to retest facts that you believe are already known:

```
select 
case when wt.testid like '%(%)%' 
then substring(wt.testid, 
        charindex('(',wt.testid)+1, 
        (charindex(')',wt.testid) - charindex('(',wt.testid) - 1)
        )
when wt.testid like '%!_% %' escape '!'
then substring(wt.testid, 
        charindex('_',wt.testid)+1, 
        (charindex(' ',wt.testid) - charindex('_',wt.testid) -1)
        )
end
```

See [SQL Server should not raise illogical errors](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32912431-sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors) if you want to share in the despair that MS seem intent on never fixing this issue.

Comment: Interesting. I was starting to come to a similar conclusion - that it was trying to run this `substring` function on data which wasn't actually included in my final result, as if it was evaluating before my `'where'` clauses took effect.   
What does `escape` do here?

Comment: @ChrisA - underscore is a wildcard character in `LIKE`. But I wanted to match a literal underscore. `ESCAPE` says what character you're using to escape characters in the `LIKE` expression so they have their literal meaning.